# Airflow dag does not have output

Tags: python, output, airflow

I used bashOperator to call an existing python script, but no output printed after executing DAG and it is regarded as failed.

This is the log from airflow:

*** Reading local file: /home/test/airflow/logs/CallP/execution/2020-07-02T01:10:37.440062+00:00/1.log

```
    [2020-07-02 10:41:04,068] {taskinstance.py:669} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: CallP.execution 2020-07-02T01:10:37.440062+00:00 [queued]>

    [2020-07-02 10:41:04,094] {taskinstance.py:669} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: CallP.execution 2020-07-02T01:10:37.440062+00:00 [queued]>
    [2020-07-02 10:41:04,095] {taskinstance.py:879} INFO - 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [2020-07-02 10:41:04,095] {taskinstance.py:880} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
    [2020-07-02 10:41:04,095] {taskinstance.py:881} INFO - 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [2020-07-02 10:41:04,111] {taskinstance.py:900} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): execution> on 2020-07-02T01:10:37.440062+00:00
    [2020-07-02 10:41:04,113] {standard_task_runner.py:53} INFO - Started process 86541 to run task
    [2020-07-02 10:41:04,189] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: CallP.execution 2020-07-02T01:10:37.440062+00:00 [running]> test-HP-Z210-Workstation
    [2020-07-02 10:41:04,219] {bash_operator.py:82} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
     /tmp
    [2020-07-02 10:41:04,220] {bash_operator.py:103} INFO - Temporary script location: /tmp/airflowtmpu511x1ra/execution3ydgjnkm
    [2020-07-02 10:41:04,220] {bash_operator.py:115} INFO - Running command: python3 /home/test/airflow/scripts/CallTypes.py
    [2020-07-02 10:41:04,226] {bash_operator.py:122} **INFO - Output:**
    [2020-07-02 10:41:57,434] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - Command exited with return code 1
    [2020-07-02 10:41:57,446] {taskinstance.py:1145} ERROR - Bash command failed
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 983, in _run_raw_task
        result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 134, in execute
        raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")
    airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed
    [2020-07-02 10:41:57,447] {taskinstance.py:1189} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.dag_id=CallP, task_id=execution, execution_date=20200702T011037, start_date=20200702T011104, end_date=20200702T011157
    [2020-07-02 10:41:59,394] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2020-07-02 10:41:59,394] {local_task_job.py:103} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

dag = DAG(dag_id='CallP', schedule_interval=None, tags=['CallP'])

```
task = BashOperator(
    task_id='execution',
    dag=dag,
    bash_command="python3 /home/test/airflow/scripts/CallTypes.py",
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    owner='airflow',
)
```

Comment: I have verified that script CallTypes.py can be executed successfully, I do not know why there is no output when called in Airflow

Comment: Could you please try to execute your command `python3 /home/test/airflow/scripts/CallTypes.py` using the same user that Airflow will use separately in command line? Will that work?

Comment: It worked if I executed the script separately. But if I call the script in Airflow, it failed.

Comment: To be clear, CallTypes.py fulfill the functionality to set up a call. When calling script from Airflow, actually call was set up. That means CallTypes.py was executed successfully , but there is no output in Airflow and it reported failure

Comment: That sounds like your `CallTypes.py` has something wrong. Could you confirm that you didn't use expressions like `sys.exit(1)`? I can only guess because this needs debugging. It's not a certain error that can troubleshoot directly.

Comment: Yes, you are right. CallTypes.py calls a sys.exit(1) at the end of execution. This issus is resolved after removing sys.exit(1). Thank you.

Comment: No problem. You don't have to remove it if you really need it for the logic, just use sys.exit(0)